# java-JNA call a native loop from Java and stop it from an other function

Tags: java, c++, jna

I want to start a loop coded in C++ that is run untill I ask it (from Java) to stop.
IE:

(in c++)

```
void loop(){
   while(!stop){
     // do something
   }
}
```

in Java:

```
MyLib.INSTANCE.loop();
```

then call something like :
MyLib.INSTANCE.stop = true;

Is it possible ?

Comment: This should be pretty easy to test, no?

Comment: Well yes, but there is different way to do it, so I prefer ask if there is a better way and a working way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *can* access a shared library's globals ([`NativeLibrary.getGlobalVariableAddress()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#getGlobalVariableAddress(java.lang.String))), it's preferable to define a dedicated function which does what you want (i.e. `MyLib.stop()`).

You also need to take care that your code is multi-thread aware, so that the compiler doesn't think your loop's `stop` cannot be changed and thus optimizes it away.  You also need to ensure that your loop doesn't monopolize the CPU; it needs to yield from time to time if you want your "stop" code to be able to run.